# Is there a special way to type in icon font URLs? Mine just appear as unicodes

Tags: html, css, font-face

The website is here:
http://rjdlee.com/projects/mobile/index.html

Even in my local copy, I was experiencing some issues where the font wouldn't refresh after changing it. I've checked the url it is attempting to read for the font and it appears to be right. Is there something wrong?

Here is the code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icons';
font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src:url('../fonts/icons.eot?-gbp2x2');
    src:url('../fonts/icons.eot?#iefix-gbp2x2') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/icons.ttf?-gbp2x2') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/icons.woff?-gbp2x2') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/icons.svg?-gbp2x2#icons') format('svg');
}
```

Here is the error:

[16:21:58.083] downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "icons" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): status=2147746065
source: http://rileedesign.com/projects/mobile/fonts/icons.ttf?-gbp2x2 @ http://rileedesign.com/projects/mobile/css/main.css

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry about that, added more detail. I just checked out the source link and there is a 403 Forbidden, could that be it?

Comment: Not sure, but that definitely needs fixing either way

Comment: I added reading permissions for all groups (744), but nothing happened. Something even weirder: when I went to my hosting provider's file manager and attempted to open the fonts folder, it just says Internal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with my hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to your .htaccess file? This can happen if certain file types are forbidden/excluded. I had the issue before and it was fixed by adding the font types as allowed, e.g.:

```
<FilesMatch ".*\.(js|JS|css|CSS|jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG|swf|SWF|xsl|XSL|svg|eot|ttf|woff)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Alright so I tried adding that into the .htaccess file, but it doesn't appear like anything happened.